# Do all developers need to participate in behaviour driven development specification writing?

Tags: bdd

I had few hours session with other 2 people in team when writing user stories.

For me it looks like wasting of time. For example - we were writing user stories for user registration feature. It looks like those are so simple things, that this specification can be written by one person.

We did not write yet tests (or how they are called) like these yet:

> Given a 5 by 5 game When I toggle the cell at (3, 2) Then the grid
>   should look like [graphics]

So I just had first impression.

The team will will be bigger than 3 people. So if connecting all the team, its will take insane amount of time. Its because - we are thinking about one thing at a time. Now like 3 people - 3 things (e.g. stories) at a time.

And I think product owners might not be happy because paying salary while not getting huge benefit.

Prepared specification is very good thing. But I think - better would be that as little as possible people write specification for a feature. And then we do meeting to discuss this specification and edit it.

I understand that later will be much more complex features than user registration. And I believe this will take even more time to prepare specification. Still - maybe as little as possible persons could make the specification, and then other people - meets and discuss it.

Also not all developers might need to discuss a feature. I think only developer who will actually work on that feature could join with specification creators and discuss.

Can BDD be done this way? Maybe I do not understand something and thats why I think its waste of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of BDD is about "3 amigos". These are a stakeholder, developer and Q&A. These positions can differ, it depends on the project and company structure.

The stakeholder is only 1 in a discussion mostly, but Q&A team or developers could have more attendees as you described in your case. There shouldn't be a rule that there must be everyone from the team. Keep the number on the minimum to be efficient, BUT MAINLY keep it optimal to be able to properly understand and describe the problem. It depends on a complexity of the feature. From my experience, mostly the optimal number is 2 developers.

Answer (score 1):

There's no silver bullet to BDD. You'll be continuously learning how to smooth the process further by trial/error and experience. There's no definite right and no definite wrong. I would say that first of all, no-one should feel like they are wasting their time. If that's the case, that's a smell that things could be improved or that not everyone is committed to practice BDD.

In your case, being such a small team, it definitely makes sense to get everyone involved with the definition of the features. When the team/s grow then you need to start thinking on scheduling those discussions with `just` the right stakeholders.

You have to think that the whole point of BDD is to help translating business requirements and concepts into software that can ensure that those business requirements are met. You can do this by describing the features of your product, by providing concrete examples, you can even do a full UX approach using BDD (which I would not recommend, maintenance nightmare).

Who knows how the business works/should work? Get those experts into the conversation. Who are going to be developing the feature? Get those people into the conversation. Will there be QA involvement by means of manual testing or updating existing test suites? Get them into the conversation too.

All those stakeholders are important and key to the success of BDD. Once they are all part of the conversation, the business expert should explain what they know about the feature that needs to be built. Then the rest of stakeholders should ask questions, clarifications, examples, etc. Then ideally, you'd start drafting your scenarios for the feature using Gherkin or a variant of it. Once those scenarios fully describe how the feature should work and everyone is happy with how they are written, the session would come to an end.

From there, implementation phase for developers and QA teams, and the expert to wait until all those scenarios that were described during the session are executable and are passing.

Now think about a developer that was not part of the initial conversation of the feature but needs to change its behaviour or fix a bug. That developer will have a full description on how the feature should work in plain English, and can quickly detect where those changes in behaviour might be introduced. For that, that person should gather again the appropriate stakeholders and agree on the new description of the feature. Develop, demo, celebrate.

Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing with BDD is communication and a common understanding of what you are about to implement.

One way of getting this common understanding is to have a three amigos meeting. Bring a product owner, a tester and a developer together and have them discuss a user story. This could be done using example mapping as described here by Matt Wynne: https://cucumber.io/blog/2015/12/08/example-mapping-introduction

The formal Gherkin is probably not written during the three amigos meeting, it is probably written afterwards by the developer or tester. If it written at all.

If you are satisfied with the understanding you came up with during the meeting and don't need more to be able to implement your feature you can probably skip writing Gherkin.

If you will automate the scenarios, write the Gherkin as this will be your base for the automation work.

I like automating stuff so i would probably automate the steps. You may or may not find it beneficiary and therefore do what is best for your team and project.

Creating a common understanding is mandatory, automating as not mandatory.